# How to multiply values in objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create a function where I can multiply the values of an object and return the sum.

for example:

```
let object = {
  'a': 4, 
  'b': 10,
  'c': 5
}
```

my code looks like this:

```
function sumOfValues(testObject) {
  let sumOfValues = (a * b * c)
  return sumOfValues
}


let testObject = {
  'a': 4, 
  'b': 10,
  'c': 5
}


sumOfValues(testObject)
```

Comment: `sumOfValues = (a * b * c)` ->  `sumOfValues = (testObject.a * testObject.b * testObject.c)`

Comment: ...and note that you don't need the single quotes in the object literals. You only need quotes around property names that aren't valid identifier names.

Answer (score 5):

You could get all values from the object and return the product of all values.

```js
function productOfValues(object) {
    return Object.values(object).reduce((a, b) => a * b);
}

console.log(productOfValues({ a: 4, b: 10, c: 5 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function works, but you missed the step where you use the object that is passed to the function.

If you always expect an object with `a`, `b` and `c` keys, then you could use an [object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to use expose and use those keys inside the `sumOfValues` function.

```js
function sumOfValues({ a, b, c }) {
  let sumOfValues = (a * b * c)
  return sumOfValues
}


let testObject = {
  'a': 4, 
  'b': 10,
  'c': 5
}


console.log(sumOfValues(testObject))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let object = {
  'a': 4, 
  'b': 10,
  'c': 5
}

let mult = 1;

for(let key of Object.keys(object)){
  mult *= object[key]
}

console.log(mult)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object has only 3 properties i.e. `a,b,c` then its straight forward,

```
const sumOfValues = (obj) => { return obj.a * obj.b * obj.c; }
```

But if the keys are variable and dynamic then you need the following,

```
const sumOfValues = (obj) => { 
    let sum = 1;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => sum = sum*obj[key]);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Especially when additional inputs were given